# how to make line after 2 rows in crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

how to make line after 2 rows in crystal report ?

ex:

aaaaaa

bbbbbb

---

cccccc

ddddddd

---

(working in C#)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another detail section, put the line object inside it, add this suppress formula to the new detail section...

```
remainder(recordnumber, 3) <> 0
```

Comment: thank's for the help, can i get more detail's ?
I dont know how to do it

Comment: how to add another details section? or how to enter a suppress formula?

Comment: how to enter a suppress formula to line

Comment: it's called the *section expert*, you select the new details sub section, and then to the right you'll see the *suppress* checkbox and also a little button. Hit that button to enter that formula above to control the suppression.

Comment: the formula button has "x+2" as the label

Comment: the line itself does not have a suppress formula. this is why you must use a details section.